# Types of sitemap?

Tags: seo, sitemap

How many types of sitemap are present related to RSS?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little bit vague. First, Sitemap is a specification itself while RSS is an other specification. Both specifications belong to XML format.

Despite RSS is a specific specification, some search engines allows RSS/Atom feeds to be submitted as simple Sitemaps.
However, If you submit a RSS feed you won't be able to take advantage of all Sitemap features such as the priority attribute. Also, RSS/Atom feeds can only be compared with classic Sitemaps. They won't work as News/Video/Code/... Sitemaps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should find this [Google link](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40318) very useful and informative.

Answer (score 0):

Also take note of ROR which expands upon RSS. ROR was quite popular in a period... Even though **no** major search engines announced support for any of the ROR extensions :)